# SQL trigger update and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have three table `OUTPUT` , `INVENTORY` and `PRODUCT`

```
Create Table OUTPUT(){
       OUTPUTID int indentity, -- output ID
       PRODUCTID varchar(10),
       QUANTUM int,
}
Create Table INVENTORY(){
       INVENTORYID int indentity, -- inventory ID
       QUANTUM int,
       QUANTUMOUT int, -- quantum out
}
Create Table PRODUCT(){
       PRODUCTID varchar(10),
}
```

I have created the following trigger :

```
create trigger [dbo].[trig_OUTPUT]
on [dbo].[OUTPUT]
after insert,update
as
begin
 Set nocount on;

    UPDATE INVENTORY 
    set INVENTORY.QUANTUMOUT = OUT.QUANTUM 
    from OUTPUT 
    inner join PRODUCT    on OUTPUT.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.PRODUCTID 
    inner join INVENTORY  on PRODUCT.PRODUCT = INVENTORY.PRODUCT

end
```

and stored procedure

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[spud_addOUTPUT]
@productID varchar(10),
@quantum int
AS

 declare @quantumtemp int

  set @quantumtemp = (select QUANTUM from INVENTORY where INVENTORY.PRODUCTID = @productID)

if(@quantumtemp> @quantum or ISNULL(@quantumtemp,'0')='0')
 begin
    INSERT OUTPUT(PRODUCTID,QUANTUM) values(@productID,@quantum)
 end
else
  begin
    print 'do not insert quantum out greater quantum in inventory'
  end
```

However,a stored procedure only works on the first, then I call a stored procedure. it didn't update column `QUANTUMOUT` in `INVENTORY`

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what logic you are using here but I have fixed the syntactical errors,

Never use sql server key words for your object names, if you do have any objects named any of the key words, use square brackets `[]` around them always.

**Trigger**

```
create trigger [dbo].[trig_OUTPUT]
on [dbo].[OUTPUT]
after insert,update
as
begin
 Set nocount on;

    UPDATE INVENTORY 
    set INVENTORY.QUANTUMOUT = [OUTPUT].QUANTUM   --<-- this should be OUTPUT
    from [OUTPUT] 
    inner join PRODUCT    on [OUTPUT].PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.PRODUCTID 
    inner join INVENTORY  on PRODUCT.PRODUCT = INVENTORY.PRODUCT

end
```

**Procedure**

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[spud_addOUTPUT]
@productID varchar(10),
@quantum int
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
 declare @quantumtemp int

SELECT TOP 1 @quantumtemp = QUANTUM from INVENTORY where PRODUCTID = @productID

if(@quantumtemp> @quantum or ISNULL(@quantumtemp,'0')='0')
 begin
    INSERT INTO dbo.[OUTPUT](PRODUCTID,QUANTUM) 
    values(@productID,@quantum)
 end
else
  begin
    print 'do not insert quantum out greater quantum in inventory'
  end
END
```